# Visual studio get int value in hexadecimal format

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Why I get these question marks, do I have to change the encoding or something? Can I create a unicode point from hexadecimal or int and then just do:

```
char output = convertedValue;
```

Here`s my code for the task above:

Comment: You didn't post your code... Try to provide a [minmal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on?

```
    public class UpdateInvoice : BaseInvoice
{
    public bool booked { get; set; }//
    public int? balance { get; set; }//
    public string paidDate { get; set; }//
    public bool sent { get; set; }//
}
```